# Disable Mail App in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, email

I'm using Windows 8.1 and Outlook 2013.   Is there a way to disable the Mail app that came with Windows 8.1?    I tried to delete the email accounts but no long.   Any help would be great.   Thanks.

David

Answer (score 3):

You can uninstall the mail app simply by right-clicking it, and selecting uninstall. You can re-install the mail app from the Windows Store if you wish to undo it.