# To remove or disable the Yahoo! mail app on my Win 8.1 PC

Tags: yahoo-mail

Could you tell me how to remove or disable the Yahoo! mail app on my Win 8.1 PC? Because I need to use my desktop Outlook as my default mailing system. But now Yahoo! mail app works as the default. So how can I do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set Outlook as the default mail client?
1. Open Outlook
2. Click File.
3. Click Options.
4. Under the general tab, Tick the tick-box that says: Make Outlook the default program for e-mail, contacts and calendar.

You can also uninstall yahoo mail if you like (use the programs and features - uninstall a program section in control panel) but if you don't use it again / 
accept prompts to use it as the default mail client Outlook will do the business from now on.

**OP's Update** : [This link also helped me.](https://superuser.com/questions/897862/disable-mail-app-in-windows-8-1)